# Existence of a function satisfying given conditions

Tags: real-analysis

I was going through the topic of $Function$, its boundedness, continuity etc. I got a problem.

Does there exist a function defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$ which is....

**1.** bounded;

**2.** takes its maximum and minimum values;

**3.** takes all its values between the maximum and minimum values;

Then can we conclude that then this function is continuous at some points or subintervals on
$[a,b]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function below satisfies all three conditions above but it is
discontinuous at every point on $[-1,1]$

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $x = 0$}\\
x,&\text{if x is rational, $x \neq 0$ , $x\neq 1$}\\
-x,&\text{if x is rational, $x \neq 0$ , $x\neq 1$,  $x\neq -1$} \\
0,&\text{if x = 1}
\end{cases}$

It is impossible to draw the graph of the function $y = f(x)$ but the sketch below gives an idea of its behavior.

[image]

Hence answer is no.

You can find this example in counter examples in calculus.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=1-x$ if $x$ is irrational. Well, okay, that's continuous at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, so just set $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(1/2) = 0$ and use the rule I gave above for all other values of $x$. :)